# Onscroll native event update all same type wrapper components

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I have a wrapper flat list component used in react navigation library. 
This component is in different stacknavigation tab to handle the header's animation.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Constants } from 'expo';
// import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {
  Animated,
  Dimensions,
  // PanResponder,
  // Platform,
  // ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  // ScrollView,
  // StatusBar,
  // Text,
  // TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  // View
} from "react-native";
// import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";

// Get screen dimensions
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

const AnimatedFlatList = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(FlatList);
const HEADER_HEIGHT= 40;
const FILTER_HEIGHT= 50;
const STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = Constants.statusBarHeight;
const NAVBAR_HEIGHT = HEADER_HEIGHT+FILTER_HEIGHT-2;
const scrollAnim = new Animated.Value(0);
const offsetAnim = new Animated.Value(0);

export default class AnimatedFlatListComp extends React.PureComponent {
  // Define state
  state = {
    scrollAnim,
    offsetAnim,
    clampedScroll: Animated.diffClamp(
      Animated.add(
        scrollAnim.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: [0, 1],
          extrapolateLeft: 'clamp',
        }),
        offsetAnim,
      ),
      0,
      // NAVBAR_HEIGHT - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT,
      HEADER_HEIGHT //i mede this one cuz the code abode not work is the value 40
    ),
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('smontoooo');
    // this._isMounted = false;
    // Don't forget to remove the listeners!
    // this.state.scrollAnim.removeAllListeners();
    // this.state.offsetAnim.removeAllListeners();
    this._disableListener();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._clampedScrollValue = 0;
    this._offsetValue = 0;
    this._scrollValue = 0;
    this._enableLister()
    this._handleScroll()
  }

  _onMomentumScrollBegin = () => {
    console.log('_onMomentumScrollBegin');
      clearTimeout(this._scrollEndTimer);
  }

  _onScrollEndDrag = () => {
    this._scrollEndTimer = setTimeout(this._onMomentumScrollEnd, 250);
  }

  _onMomentumScrollEnd = () => {
    console.log('_onMomentumScrollEnd');
    console.log(this._scrollValue, NAVBAR_HEIGHT, this._clampedScrollValue, (NAVBAR_HEIGHT - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT) / 2);
    const toValue = this._scrollValue > NAVBAR_HEIGHT &&
      this._clampedScrollValue > (NAVBAR_HEIGHT - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT) / 2
      ? this._offsetValue + NAVBAR_HEIGHT
      : this._offsetValue - NAVBAR_HEIGHT;

    Animated.timing(this.state.offsetAnim, {
      toValue,
      duration: 350,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }

  _handleScroll = () => this.props._handleScroll(this.state.clampedScroll)

  // _handleScroll = event => {
  //   const { y } = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset;
  //   // // console.log(y);
  //   this.setState({ scrollOffset: y }, () => {
  //     this.props._handleScroll(this.state.clampedScroll)
  //   });
  //
  // };

  _scrollToTop = () => {
    console.log('_scrollToTop');
    if (!!this.flatListRef) {
      // this.flatListRef.getNode().scrollTo({ y: 0, animated: true });
      this.flatListRef.getNode().scrollToOffset({ offset: 0, animated: true });
    }
  };

  _enableLister = () => {
    // this._firstMountFunction();
    this.state.scrollAnim.addListener(({ value }) => {
      // This is the same calculations that diffClamp does.
      const diff = value - this._scrollValue;
      this._scrollValue = value;
      this._clampedScrollValue = Math.min(
        Math.max(this._clampedScrollValue + diff, 0),
        NAVBAR_HEIGHT - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT,
      );
    });
    this.state.offsetAnim.addListener(({ value }) => {
      this._offsetValue = value;
    });
  }

  _disableListener = () => {
    this.state.scrollAnim.removeAllListeners();
    this.state.offsetAnim.removeAllListeners();
  }

  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString();

  // _onScroll = event => {
  // 
  // }

  render() {

    return (
      <AnimatedFlatList
        {...this.props}
        ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this.state.scrollAnim}}}],
          {
            useNativeDriver: true,
            // listener: this._handleScroll
          },
        )}
        // onScroll={this._onScroll}
        removeClippedSubviews={true}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        onMomentumScrollBegin={this._onMomentumScrollBegin}
        onMomentumScrollEnd={this._onMomentumScrollEnd}
        onScrollEndDrag={this._onScrollEndDrag}
        scrollEventThrottle={1}
      />

    );
  }
}
```

this is the parent

```
_handleScroll = clampedScroll => this.setState({ clampedScroll: clampedScroll })
render(){
const { clampedScroll } = this.state;
      //
      const navbarTranslate = clampedScroll.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, NAVBAR_HEIGHT - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT],
        outputRange: [0, -(NAVBAR_HEIGHT - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT)],
        extrapolate: 'clamp',
      });
return (
          <AnimatedFlatList
            // debug={true}
            ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
            maxToRenderPerBatch={4}
            contentContainerStyle={{
              paddingTop: NAVBAR_HEIGHT+STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT,
            }}
            data={this.state.dataSource}
            renderItem={
              ({item, index}) =>
                <CardAgenda
                  item={JSON.parse(item.JSON)}
                  ChangeSelectedEvent={this.ChangeSelectedEvent}
                  colorTrail={JSON.parse(item.colorTrail)}
                  // _sendBackdata={this._getChildrenCategoryData}
                  searchData={JSON.parse(item.searchData)}
                  NumAncillary={item.NumAncillary}
                  indexItinerary={item.id}
                  index={index}
                />
            }
            ListEmptyComponent={this._emptyList}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{width: width-40, backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)', height: 1, marginTop: 20, marginLeft: 20, marginRight: 20}}/>}
            _handleScroll={this._handleScroll}
          />
)}
```

Its working fine but onscroll event triggers the this.state.scrollAnim variable of ALL wrappers.
I mean if i scroll up the first AnimatedFlatList the header goes up but also the different one header in new navigation page goes up.

The correct behavior must be that all header must be independent to the own flatlist.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Information provided is not enough. If you could share the whole component and how scrollAnim is handled we might give a suggestion.

Comment: updated the code so you can see all the wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are setting up a reference to the state when creating animated Values obj. You should not keep them as constants outside your class boundary.

Try remove your following constants.

```
const scrollAnim = new Animated.Value(0);
const offsetAnim = new Animated.Value(0);
```

Then define them inside the constructor.

```
 export default class AnimatedFlatListComp extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.scrollAnim = new Animated.Value(0);
   this.offsetAnim = new Animated.Value(0);
   // Define state
   state = {
        scrollAnim: this.scrollAnim,
        offsetAnim:  this.offsetAnim,
        clampedScroll: Animated.diffClamp(
          Animated.add(
            this.scrollAnim.interpolate({
              inputRange: [0, 1],
              outputRange: [0, 1],
              extrapolateLeft: 'clamp',
            }),
           this.offsetAnim,
          ),
        0,
        // NAVBAR_HEIGHT - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT,
        HEADER_HEIGHT //i mede this one cuz the code abode not work is 
        the value 40
        ),
      };
    }
```

Comment: If i do ```state = {
    scrollAnim: new Animated.Value(0),
    offsetAnim: new Animated.Value(0),
    clampedScroll: Animated.diffClamp(
      Animated.add(
        this.state.scrollAnim.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: [0, 1],
          extrapolateLeft: 'clamp',
        }),
        this.state.offsetAnim,
      ),
      0,
      HEADER_HEIGHT //i made this one cuz the code abode not work is the value 40
    ),
  };``` i get this error ```TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.scrollAnim')```

Comment: Updated code! Please understand the concept and make changes accordingly. DON'T COPY PASTE THE CODE.

Comment: Solved creating this.clampedScroll into componentDidMount. Thanks!

Comment: Also you can do it inside the constructor! I updated the code.